# How to trigger the user account token stake or unstake automatically by using contract

Tags: smart-contract

Actually , I have a scenario that users need to stake his or her own certain tokens on a platform by using eosio contract without worrying the platform will take over  the users's tokens.  and some conditions, say 10 days later, would return back the tokens to its original owner. 
so, my question is :

```
How to freeze the user's tokens temporarily
```

I tried to have 2 ideas for this scenario but i think they are  not good ideas.

```
first, I could let user create a new account and then transfer his tokens to that new account. but the owner of this new account is a problem

second, I could let user stake equality eos by buying ram but how to sale it is a problem.
```

so, is there any a better idea for this ?

Comment: Are you trying to automate this so token holders can avoid getting their tokens auctioned off as stated in the Article XV of the current EOS constitution? Automated staking/unstaking sounds like automated (bot) voting and I think I read in the Introducing EOSIO Dawn 4.0 article on medium.com that even though automated voting by bots may be hard to detect, it would be possible to prove that people do not use smart contracts to auto-vote. I thought I share this as a caution. :)

Comment: May be I can have a try following your idea, thanks for your help , but still one question , would the unstaked eos be released 3 days later?

Comment: As far as I know unstaking always returns tokens after 3 days.

Comment: That would be unacceptable for my scenario. and still thank you :)